# Accessing certificates of another user via impersonation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, certificate, x509, impersonation

I need to digitally sign PDF documents on a web server running ASP.NET Core 2.2 in IIS. The web app is running with a service user and the impersonation shall be done in the code. The problem is, I can't access the users certificates via the X509Store class. I tried to create a minimal example which only impersonates a different user and outputs the certificates in the console. I ran it as an administrator but no certifiactes were found.

Permissions I granted in the "Local Group Policy Editor" (gpedit.msc) under "Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Management":

- Act as part of the operating system: Added ServiceUser
- Allow log on locally: Added UserToBeImpersonated
- Log on as batch job: Added UserToBeImpersonated
- Create a token object: Added ServiceUser
- Replace a process level token: Added ServiceUser
- Adjust Memory Quotas for a process: Added ServiceUser

For the impersonation I used the SimpleImpersonation from https://github.com/mj1856/SimpleImpersonation and extended it to also load the user profile like this:

```
public static void RunAsUser(UserCredentials credentials, LogonType logonType, Action action)
{
    // this method tells Windows to dynamically determine where to look for the HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry hive,
    // rather than using the cached location from when the process was initially invoked
    RegDisablePredefinedCache();

    using (var tokenHandle = credentials.Impersonate(logonType))
    using (var profileToken = credentials.ImpersonateUserProfile(tokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle()))
    {
        RunImpersonated(tokenHandle, _ => action());
    }
}       

internal UserProfileToken ImpersonateUserProfile(IntPtr tokenHandle)
{
    var tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

    // Not sure if the token needs to be duplicated or not
    if (DuplicateToken(tokenHandle, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) == 0)
        HandleError(tokenHandle);

    // Load User profile
    var profileInfo = new ProfileInfo();
    profileInfo.dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(profileInfo);
    profileInfo.lpUserName = _username;
    profileInfo.dwFlags = 1;

    // LoadUserProfile() failed
    if (!LoadUserProfile(tokenDuplicate, ref profileInfo))
        HandleError(tokenDuplicate);

    // LoadUserProfile() failed - HKCU handle was not loaded
    if (profileInfo.hProfile == IntPtr.Zero)
        HandleError(tokenDuplicate);

    return new UserProfileToken() { ProfileInfo = profileInfo, Token = tokenDuplicate };
}

public class UserProfileToken : IDisposable
{
    public ProfileInfo ProfileInfo { get; set; }

    public IntPtr Token { get; set; }

    ~UserProfileToken()
    {
        Dispose();
    }

    private bool isDisposed = false;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (isDisposed) return;
        isDisposed = true;

        UnloadUserProfile(Token, ProfileInfo.hProfile);
    }
}
       
[DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool LoadUserProfile(IntPtr hToken, ref ProfileInfo lpProfileInfo);

[DllImport("Userenv.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool UnloadUserProfile(IntPtr hToken, IntPtr lpProfileInfo);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken, int impersonationLevel, ref IntPtr hNewToken);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int RegDisablePredefinedCache();
```

The main code for the testing looks like this:

```
var credentials = new Impersonator.UserCredentials(domain, username, password);
Impersonator.RunAsUser(credentials, Impersonator.LogonType.Interactive, () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Current user: {WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name}");
    
    var store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

    if (store.Certificates.Count == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No Certificates found.");
    }
    else
    {
        var certCount = 0;
        foreach (var cert in store.Certificates)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[{certCount}] Subject: {cert.Subject}");
            Console.WriteLine($"[{certCount}] Issuer: {cert.Issuer}");

            certCount++;
        }
    }
});
```

Unfortunately no certificats are found when the same code (without impersonation) shows two certificates on the target users machine.

Another interesting thing I found on the server is that the users profile directory under C:\Users<username> has not the users name but some Chinese? characters. When checking the user profiles in the system settings the username is correct though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the impersonation (with loading the profile) does not trigger the Auto-Enrollment for receiving the certificate from the certificate authority. This must be done seperately with something like this:

```
using CERTENROLLLib;

public static void EnrollUserCertificateByTemplate(string templateName, string subjectName, string friendlyName = null)
    {
        var enrollment = new CX509Enrollment();

        // Set target store
        enrollment.InitializeFromTemplateName(X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextUser, templateName);

        var request = enrollment.Request;
        var innerRequest = request.GetInnerRequest(InnerRequestLevel.LevelInnermost);
        var innerRequestPkcs10 = innerRequest as IX509CertificateRequestPkcs10;

        // Set the subject name
        var distinguishedName = new CX500DistinguishedName();
        distinguishedName.Encode(subjectName, X500NameFlags.XCN_CERT_NAME_STR_NONE);            
        innerRequestPkcs10.Subject = distinguishedName;

        // Set the friendly name
        if (friendlyName != null) enrollment.CertificateFriendlyName = friendlyName;

        // Enroll for the certificate into MY store if it is successfully issued by CA
        enrollment.Enroll();
    }
```

Additionaly you need to check if there is already a valid certificate available in the users certificate store. Otherwise you add a certificate everytime you impersonate (and execute the code above).

Anothr thing I needed to do was giving Administrative rights to the executing user. All the other permissions posted in my question could be remove.

Comment: Did you have to give admin rights or would the auto-enrollment + original permissions granted work also? Giving a user admin rights used for a web app seems like one step away from being exploited.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't manage to get it working without admin rights to this day.

Comment: Thank's for the reply. The weird thing I have is that using impersonation to access cert store of specific user it was working fine for ages. 5th Dec 2022 it stopped. Console app test app to use least amount of code will fail continuously for part of the day and then with no code changes the same test app will start working. It's almost as if it goes "it's 12noon now so I'll work for a bit before failing again". This is accessing an external WCF  API using a client certificate. If the test app is run as the impersonated user it always works.